# \align* inside minipage inside \align*: Argument of \align* has an extra }

Tags: align, minipage

My document is obviously much more complex than this, but my reproduction is simple:

```
\documentclass{letter}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
  stuff &=
    \begin{minipage}[t]{4cm}
      \begin{align*}
        a & b
      \end{align*}
    \end{minipage}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

If I remove `& b` it works.  How do I get it working with the ampersand?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hide the inner alignment with `{..}`

```
\documentclass{letter}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
  stuff &=
    {\begin{minipage}[t]{4cm}
      \begin{align*}
        a & b
      \end{align*}
    \end{minipage}}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're probably looking for `aligned`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
stuff &=
\begin{aligned}[t]
  a &+ b + c + d \\
    &+ e + f + g
\end{aligned} \\
&= uuu
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]